# Java String Conditional Break Not Working

Tags: java, conditional-statements, break

I wrote a simple program which prompts the user to enter a sentence, word, or number, and then prints input is art. I put the program on an infinite loop so that the prompt would repeat. However, now I'm trying to add a way to quit by saying `if (input == "quit") break;` however it does not seem to be working. It just continues the infinite loop. Here is the full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Art
{
     public static void main(String [] args)
     {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a;
       for ( ; ; ) 
            {
            System.out.println("Please enter something: ");
            a = input.nextLine();
            if (a == "quit") break;
            System.out.print("\n");
            System.out.println(a + " is art.");
            System.out.print("\n");


            }
    }
}
```

Any help would be lovely, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `input.equals("quit")`.

The `==` is used to check whether two objects are the exact same instance - the same thing in memory -which the typed word and the constant string `"quit"` are **not**. Two instances of `"quit"` were created: one typed by the user, and one constant in the program.

The `equals()` method is used to compare whether two objects are equal in whatever way equality is defined for them. For strings, that would mean having the same text.

The difference between `==` and `equals()` is really fundamental in Java, so you should go over it. Here's [a good SO post on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion). Once you start creating your own classes, you will probably be implementing `equals()` methods for them.  For that reason, make sure to go over the [`equals()` / `hashCode()` contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java) as well.

Answer (score 1):

looks like the `a == "quit"` is the problem. Compare strings using `equals()`

```
if("quit".equals(a)) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I'll accept it in 11 minutes.